# How to add multiple images with their captions using POST.getlist in django

Tags: django, django-views, jquery-file-upload

I am working with multiple image uploader using blueimp jquery file upload in django. I am uploading multiple images with caption to database. But I am getting some difficulties. I want to save the image with its caption and I am using

```
file = request.FILES['files[]']
caption = request.POST.get('captions[]')
```

But when I use POST.get it returns only the last value of a list. Also I tried to use POST.getlist as

```
caption = request.POST.getlist('captions[]')
for c in caption:
  thefile = FileUploaded(captions = str(c), upFile=file)
  thefile.save()
```

but in this case when I save my file, the files are saved in 1X1 or 2X2 or 3X3... i.e., when I save 3 image with its 3 captions, then data is save in 3X3 matrices. But I want only 3 data not 9 data. 
Thanks in advance.